# Error al pasar de programa a libreria para generar documentos LibreOffice

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

Me he bajado un programa de codeproject:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38425/%2FArticles%2F38425%2FHow-to-Read-and-Write-ODF-ODS-Files-OpenDocument-2

Dicho programa se usa para crear y leer ficheros .ods/odf (LibreOffice),
cuando lanzo el programa al llegar a la línea:

```
Ionic.Zip.ZipFile templateFile = this.GetZipFile(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("OdsReadWrite.template.ods"));
```

carga bien la templateFile y posteriormente me genera el fichero.

Mi intención es transformar dicho programa en una librería para poder usarlo en otro programa.

He transformado dicho programa y lo compila bien.
Sin embargo, al llamar a la librería desde otro programa, al llegar a la linea anteriormente escrita salta la excepción:

> The stream must be non-null" & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: zipStream

Existe un fichero en el programa que se llama template.ods que es el que usa el programa para rellenarlo y luego guardarlo con el nombre elegido, no se si tengo que poner algo especifico para que se compile internamente con la librería o no y ese pueda ser el problema

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para que un fichero se copie junto al resultado de la compilación de un proyecto, debes indicarlo en el propio fichero.

Desde el Visual Studio -> Explorador de Soluciones selecciona el fichero que quieres y haz Click Derecho -> Propiedades. Ahí veras una propiedad " Copiar en el directorio de resultados", cambiala a "Copiar Siempre".